# How to exclude an HTML tag in regex search

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, powergrep

I'm using powerGrep to find instances of these:

> BLOCK 1:

```
<td class="danish">kat
<?php audioButton("../../audio/words/dog","dog");?></td>
```

But there are also instances of these among my files:

> BLOCK 2

```
<td class="danish">kat</td>
<td><?php audioButton("../../audio/words/dog","dog");?></td>
```

I want to find BLOCK 1 only, not BLOCK 2.

I've tried using (?!), as in

```
.*<td class(.*?)>(.*)(?!</td>)
.*<\?php audioButton\("(.*)/.*",".*"\);.*\?></td>
```

Can I somehow exclude the `</td>` tag from the search, so that BLOCK 2 is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you really want to match the first cell tag only, but to perform this you can try:

`<td[^>]*>\s*(?:.(?!</td>))+\s*<\?php audioButton\("[^"]*/(.+?)","(.*?)"\);.*?\?>.*?</td>` with `g` flag.

see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/tI4rL4/1

**[EDIT]**

You can also see the replacement of `dog` to `cat` here: https://regex101.com/r/tI4rL4/2

It may not be perfect, since the question is a bit too vague, but it works. If you need to refine a bit or adjust or need a bit of explanation you can ask me!

Comment: Hi Antoni. Thanks a lot for helping :)  I guess my question could have been clearer. I've edited it now, so hopefully it's more understandable. I don't want it to match any instances of Block 2.

Comment: Yes it is what I first understood, so if you go to the link of my demo it does match only block 1 `dog` instances and not block 2 `dog` instances. Isn't it what you want? :)

Comment: Yes! That's what I want! Thank you very much :)